# SfPdfViewer.asset() not showing the PDF in Chrome (syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer package); I am new at flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, syncfusion

The PDF is not showing in the Chrome browser when the SfPdfViewer.asset function is used.

Here is the build method used when displaying the page:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("My PDF Document"),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SfPdfViewer.asset('assets/patientForm.pdf'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

patientForm.pdf is added to the assets folder at the root of the file and to pubspec.yaml (under flutter) like this:

```
 assets:
    - assets/patientForm.pdf
```

When the page is loaded, only the AppBar is shown and the rest of the page is blank.

I have double checked the spelling of the file name and a 404 error is not showing up, so it means that the file was found. Is there another mistake the code?

I have tried to clean flutter and re-run it, and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suspect that you might have missed the script part in the web/index.html file. Kindly include the following script in the web/index.html file.

UG documentation: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/getting-started#add-the-flutter-pdf-viewer-to-an-application

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.11.338/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
   pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.11.338/pdf.worker.min.js";    
</script>
```

Note: As the SfPdfViewer widget is already scrollable, it is not recommended to use the SfPdfViewer widget inside a SingleChildScrollView widget.